# How can I create voltmeter with Zener diodes?

Tags: led, resistors, voltage-measurement, zener

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f41ZmA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

5 LEDS

- One LED is to remain always on when current is passed through.
- One LED will turn on when voltage is between 50 to 90 volts.
- One LED will turn on when voltage is between 90 to 150 volts.
- One LED will turn on when voltage is between 150 to 280 volts.
- One LED will turn on when voltage is greater than 280 volts.

What I have in mind is 5 LEDS, 5 Zener diodes for each range and resistors. Could logic gates come in handy?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise that this is not a free design
house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied
out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question
shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your
post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and
findings so far, in considerable detail. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome. I have hand drawn my design but I don't know how I can upload it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I suggest you edit your question and use the built in schematic editor to draw your schematic. This way people can edit your schematic to show improvements.

Comment: What is done usually (and is simpler to design) is that several LEDs will be on depending on the input voltage. E.g. for low voltage, only LED1 is on, for <90V, both LED1 and LED2 are on, etc... and for >280V, all LEDs are on. Is this what you want, or do you absolutely need no more than one LED on at a given time?

Comment: Ideally I would like 5 LEDS as described but I fully understand your idea. I am open to that suggestion though. I will upload my idea.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to build a digital voltmeter using a microcontroller (or buy one, for that matter)? Zener diodes are inferior in many ways.

Comment: How would you do it with an MCU?

Comment: If you want to buy one, this is done by typing "LED digital voltmeter" in your preferred shopping search box. If you want to build one yourself, you should be typing "Arduino digital voltmeter" in a search engine.

Comment: One LED to rule them all, one LED to find them.  One LED to bring them all, and in the darkness bind them.

Comment: This is such an extreme case of [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This is what I found. How could you make it simpler?

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 LEDs. One will always be on, and the other 4 are to be controlled. Consider getting a quad analog comparator, and use these to trip at 50/90/150/280 volts. Use voltage dividers before the comparators. Have a reference voltage at 2 volts, or 3 volts, or 4 volts (4.096 volts at +-1% should be cheap to buy) into one of the VIn- or Vin+ pin of each comparator.

You'll have a thermometer-code output. Its your task to define the logic behavior and provide high-current drives to the LEDS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb5l9Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Would you mind sketching it because I am having a hard time drawing it on paper? I have one led drawn before a quad analogue comparator

Comment: These are for high voltages and not low voltages

Comment: Thank you for that I can understand that now better. So does that mean each comparator will have a voltage reading set? So the voltages I have listed? Would the LEDs be placed at the output of each comparator?

Comment: Some comparators can directly drive LEDs safely, if a current-limited resistor is in series with the LED. You must decide that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for a LM3914, as it integrates many of the required functions. The low input current makes practical a simple voltage divider at the input, and the rest follows as shown on the datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf). Separate power is required, as would be the case for any comparator/logic solution, but overall this is far simpler.

Comment: What do you mean seperate power? So adding battery to power the device? What is the simplest desing in your opinion?

Comment: You need a DC supply of between 3V and 25V to power the LM3914 and the LEDs - see the data sheet. I would not advise using a battery because of the current drain, but something like a USB charger would be ideal. Note that you can parallel LM3914 outputs so you can make several voltage increments drive one LED, thus if you choose an increment of, say, 48V, you can light separate LEDs for 48 - 96V, 96 - 144V, 144 - 288V , >288V (These are input voltages before the divider!)

Answer (score 0):

Even the cheapest MCUs  have A to D converters and a voltage reference built in, so there's not a lot of external components needed to make up what is essentially a bar graph display.[image]

[Here's](http://www.twovolt.com/2016/08/27/0-to-5v-bar-graph-voltage-monitor-using-20-led-pic16f886-smd-board/)  the first one I found on a search, but you can scale this down to what you are looking for. It can be done with an 8 pin package device for this, or even a 6 pin if you're prepared to [multiplex](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/91029a.pdf)  the LEDs, and they start at under 50 cents. It'd be a very different project than doing it with discrete comparators, or with a dedicated bar graph driver like the LM3914 - so you need to decide what you aim to learn from doing this.

Comment: Looks very interesting. But I'm just worried that it wouldn't work with high voltages of up to 360v

Comment: All the suggested solutions are low voltage operation, so you scale down the input with a divider - just as happens in all multimeters.

Comment: Perfect. I will post my results and design hopefully by the end of Sunday.